# Determining what values in a system can cause infinite/unique/no solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I just did this exercise. I got the right answer except for one minor detail according to my book. I can see the reason, but I'm not sure what sort of logic did the book use to determine that. You can skip to the bottom of the question.

---

$$\begin{matrix}
px_1&+&2x_2&+&3x_3&=&2\\
px_1&+&px_2&+&(p+1)x_3&=&p\\
px_1&+&px_2&+&(2p-2)x_3&=&2p-2
\end{matrix}$$

> For what value or values of $p$ does the system have infinite
>   solutions, unique solution, and none at all?

$$\begin{bmatrix}
p&2&3\\
p&p&p+1\\
p&p&2p-2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
p\\
2p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$-r_1+r_2 \ \ , \ \ -r_1+r_3$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
p&2&3\\
0&p-2&p-2\\
0&p-2&2p-5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
p-2\\
2p-4
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$-r_2+r_3$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
p&2&3\\
0&p-2&p-2\\
0&0&p-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
p-2\\
p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

**CASE A - If $p = 2$:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2&2&3\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have infinite solutions depending on one variable.

---

**CASE B - If $p \not = 2$:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
p&2&3\\
0&p-2&p-2\\
0&0&p-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
p-2\\
p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\frac{1}{p}r_1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{1}{p-2}r_2$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2/p&3/p\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&p-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2/p\\
1\\
p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

**CASE B.1 - If $p = 3$:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2/3&3/3\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2/3\\
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have an **inconsistent** system. There is no solution for $p = 3$.

**CASE B.2 - If $p \not = 3$:**

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2/p&3/p\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&p-3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2/p\\
1\\
p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\frac{1}{p-3}r_3$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2/p&3/p\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2/p\\
1\\
(p-2)/(p-3)
\end{bmatrix}$$

We have an unique solution.

---

**ANSWER:**

- **For infinite solutions**, we need $p = 2$.
- **For unique solution**, we need $p \in \mathbb{R} - \{ 2, 3\}$.
- **For no solution**, we need $p = 3$.

---

**THE BOOK'S ANSWER:**

Exactly like my answer above, except that it says, additionally:

> For $p = 0$, there is no solution.

Hm. Let's see why. If we replace $p = 0$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&2&3\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
0\\
-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

And of course, now I see why. Since the last row is reduced to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&2&3\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

This becomes inconsistent.

---

It would have never occurred to me that $p = 0$ was a case worth branching off. So my question is: **what reasoning did the book use to decide that $p = 0$ was worth branching off?**

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
p&2&3\\
p&p&p+1\\
p&p&2p-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$\det A=p(p-2)(p-3)$$

So you should check each value of $p$ to see if the equations become over-determined, under-determined or just right.

If it is over-determined, then usually no solution.
If it is under-determined, then usually infinite solutions.
If it is just right, then usually one solution.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> what reasoning did the book use to decide that $p = 0$ was worth
>   branching off?

One approach to this kind of problems is to find any value of $p$ that would cause one or more of the following conditions to occur:

1. A redundant row (2 or more columns become equal) - This is the case when you have more equations than variables.
2. A redundant column (2 or more rows become equal) - This is the case when you have more variables than equations.
3. A row that is entirely zero
4. A column that is entirely zero
5. The Right hand-side becomes all zero - This is the case when the solution vector must all be zero.

Values of $p$ that make non-of the above possible are the values where the system has a non-zero unique solution.

When $p=0$, condition (4) arises and is observable immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The determinant of the square matrix factors as $p(p-2)(p-3)$, as can be seen from the common factor in column 1, row 2 - row 3 and column 1 - column 2.